# jQuery dataTables changes on wrapper width only take effect after loading chrome's inspector

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to resize a table using dataTables but I've spent hours trying to do it and it's impossible. If I set the width using plain CSS it works fine but my intention is to dynamically set the width and make it fit it with the width of the page:

I have the following code:

```
var winH = screen.availHeight;     
winH = winH - (winH/2) - 50;
winH = winH + "px";

winW = screen.availWidth;
winW = winW - 100;
winW = winW + "px";

var oTable = $('#tutorial-table').dataTable({
    "bFilter": false,
    "bSort": false,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bScrollCollapse": true,   
    "bInfo": true,
    "sScrollY": winH,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "sScrollX": "100%"
});
new FixedColumns( oTable, {
    "iLeftColumns": 1,
    "iLeftWidth": 130,
});        

$('#tutorial-table_wrapper').css('width', winW);
oTable.fnDraw();
```

This code above shrinks the table and shows only 1 column but if I add some CSS:

```
#tutorial-table_wrapper{
    width: 1200px;
}
```

It works ok and resizes the table to be 1200px (setting it through JS only works if I open the inspector, I supose that this is due to chrome reloading all the elements).

Is there any way to force this behaviour or to set the width in some way?

Thanks

Comment: Aren't you using any resize handler?

Comment: I have "bAutoWidth" set to false but has no effect on the global width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally fixed it by removing completely dataTables and using jquery fixed tables instead:

http://www.novasoftware.com/Download/jQuery_FixedTable/JQuery_FixedTable.aspx

Much easier to set up, very light and also much more responsive when it comes to load dynamic tables or configure parameters like width.

Regards.